# Где может быть ошибка в onScrolListener в recyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть слушатель:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                            loading = false;
                            Log.i("m","1");

                        }
                    }

                }

                if (dy >= 5) {
                    loading = true;
                }


                if (dy < 0) {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if ((pastVisiblesItems - visibleItemCount) <= 0) {
                            loading = false;
                            Log.i("m","2");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

возникла  довольно странная и непонятная ситуация. Это все затеяно для внедрение пагинации. Пробовал библиотеку от гугла для пагинации, но не получилось ее внедрить поэтому было решено создать это самому. Но проблема в том что если смотреть логи, то при достижении низа списка у меня прилетает лог от 2 до 5 раз, а если достигать верха списка то только один, но временами тоже может глючить. То есть если перевести все на запросы то у меня будет слаться 2-5 одних и тех же запросов при достижении нижней границы списка, а это не есть хорошо. Может кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде починил эту проблему добавлением еще одного параметра в условие:

```
 if (pastVisiblesItems - visibleItemCount <= 0&& !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1))
```

и:

```
 if (pastVisiblesItems - visibleItemCount <= 0&& !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1))
```

может конечно не очень правильное решение, но вроде работает так как нужно.